# SKAction fade out with duration

Tags: sprite-kit, skaction, skemitternode

I try to add a Emmiter node when I touch on the Screen and remove it (fade it out) when i release my finger. But I want the first node to stay on the screen. What am I doing wrong?

```
NSMutableArray *childs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.children];
[childs removeObjectAtIndex:0];

for (SKEmitterNode *node in childs) {
    [node runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[ [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:1], [SKAction waitForDuration:3], /*[SKAction removeFromParent]*/ ]]];
}
```

He only runs the first action  not. the other bothes work. But the fade out works when I try it with my first node:

```
[self.children[0] runAction:[SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:1]];
```

Comment: try in a simple test project whether SKEmitterNode nodes can be faded at all

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly check whether each node in the array is an instance of the SKEmitterNode class.

```
for (SKEmitterNode *node in childs) {

    if ([node isKindOfClass:[SKEmitterNode class]])
    {
        [node runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[ [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:1], [SKAction waitForDuration:3], [SKAction removeFromParent] ]]];
    }

}
```